# How to pass multiple command line arguments or system arguments in sql query which is inside the function of python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I have written a code where I want to pass 3 command line or system arguments to sql query which is inside the function which I have made. The system arguments should pass first to the function arguments and those arguments will then get pass to that sql query within the function. Those arguments will give the condition to that sql query. For example: If I want to fetch only january's data of department id 1 then the command line arguments will that month and department id.

I have tried to pass agruments from command line but It is taking my file name as a first system a system argument.

(My code):

```
def main(mon,Id):
    quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER={SQL Server};'
                                       'SERVER=servername;'
                                       'DATABASE=DB;'
                                       'uid=userid;'
                                       'pwd=****;')
    engine = 
      create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///odbc_connect{}'.format(quoted))
    sql = "select a.companyid,CAST(c.gpsdatetime AS DATE) AS GPSDate, 
      AVG(c.tempanalog1) AS AverageTemperature from Vehicle_Master 
      a,GPSEventsData c with(nolock) where a.companyid = c.customerid 
      AND datepart(month,gpsdatetime) = "+str(mon)+"  AND 
      DATEPART(dw,c.gpsdatetime) != 1  AND a.VehicleID = "+str(Id)+"  
      GROUP BY a.companyid, CAST(c.gpsdatetime AS DATE) ORDER BY            
      GPSDate"

     df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
     df['GPSDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['GPSDate'])
     g = df.groupby('companyid')

     df['Day'] = g.cumcount() + 1
     newdf = df[['companyid','Day','AverageTemperature']]

     return(newdf.to_sql("DistributorWiseParticularMonth", engine, 
     if_exists="replace"))

 import sys
 if __name__ == "__main__":
 a = sys.argv[0]
 b = sys.argv[1] 
 main(a,b)
```

## I have called the above code from command line by giving command as:

```
python distributor.py 1, 2
```

It's taking my filename i.e distributor.py as 1st argument.
And My actual argument which I am passing i.e 1, 2 as 2nd argument.

This is something I am getting.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', " 
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax 
near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: select a.companyid, CAST(c.gpsdatetime AS DATE) AS GPSDate, 
AVG(c.tempanalog1) AS AverageTemperature from Vehicle_Master 
a,GPSEventsData c with(nolock) where a.companyid = c.customerid and 
datepart(month,gpsdatetime) = distributor.py  AND a.active = 1 and 
c.gpsdatetime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0) 
AND c.gpsdatetime < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND 
DATEPART(hh,c.gpsdatetime) >= 9 AND DATEPART(hh,c.gpsdatetime) <= 19 AND  
DATEPART(dw,c.gpsdatetime) != 1  AND a.VehicleID = 1,2  GROUP BY 
a.companyid, CAST(c.gpsdatetime AS DATE) ORDER BY GPSDate]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Answer (score 0):

**What you are doing wrong.**

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script. And so when you give that, it is overrided by the name of the script.

**Simple fix**

Read arguments after index number 0. like `sys.argv[1]`, `sys.argv[2]` and so on..

*Additionally*, Python allows you to assign a sequence of items (including lists) to variable names. So if you expect the user to always supply two arguments, you can assign those arguments (as strings) to two variables:

```
user_args = sys.argv[1:]
fun, games = user_args # len(user_args) had better be 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've got the output. :)

Comment: In that case give an upvote and accept my answer, that motivates me to do more good :P

Comment: Done it already. It would be appreciated if you do the same. That might gain my confidence in asking more and more questions. ;)

Comment: I ran out of vote limits for today, but i have bookmarked this to vote up tomorrow. :)

Comment: Ohh that's very sweet of you, Thanks :)